# Numpy polyfit: possible error in the scaling of the covariance matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I am having a hard time figuring out the scaling for the covariance matrix in numpy polyfit.

In the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) I read that the scaling factor to go from an unscaled to a scaled covariance matrix is

```
chi2 / sqrt(N - DOF).
```

In the code attached below, it seems that the scaling factor actually is

```
chi2 / DOF
```

Here is my code

```
# Generate synthetically the data
# True parameters
import numpy as np

true_slope = 3
true_intercept = 7

x_data = np.linspace(-5, 5, 30)

# The y-data will have a noise term, to simulate imperfect observations
sigma = 1
y_data = true_slope * np.linspace(-5, 5, 30) + true_intercept
y_obs = y_data + np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=sigma, size=x_data.size)

# Here I generate artificially some unequal uncertainties 
# (even if there is no reason for them to be so)
y_uncertainties = sigma * np.random.normal(loc=1.0, scale=0.5*sigma, size=x_data.size)

# Make the fit
popt, pcov = np.polyfit(x_data, y_obs, 1, w=1/y_uncertainties, cov='unscaled')
popt, pcov_scaled = np.polyfit(x_data, y_obs, 1, w=1/y_uncertainties, cov=True)

my_scale_factor = np.sum((y_obs - popt[0] * x_data  - popt[1])**2 / y_uncertainties**2)\
                         / (len(y_obs)-2)

scale_factor =  pcov_scaled[0,0] / pcov[0,0]
```

If I run the code, I see that the actual scale factor is chi2 / DOF and not the value reported in the documentation. Is this true or am I missing something?

I have a further question. Why is it suggested to use just the inverse of the y-data error instead of the square of the inverse of the y-data errors for the weights in the case that the uncertainties are normally-distributed?

**Edit to add the data generated by a run of the code**

```
x_data = array([-5.        , -4.65517241, -4.31034483, -3.96551724, -3.62068966,
   -3.27586207, -2.93103448, -2.5862069 , -2.24137931, -1.89655172,
   -1.55172414, -1.20689655, -0.86206897, -0.51724138, -0.17241379,
    0.17241379,  0.51724138,  0.86206897,  1.20689655,  1.55172414,
    1.89655172,  2.24137931,  2.5862069 ,  2.93103448,  3.27586207,
    3.62068966,  3.96551724,  4.31034483,  4.65517241,  5.        ])

y_obs = array([-7.27819725, -8.41939411, -3.9089926 , -5.24622589, -3.78747379,
   -1.92898727, -1.375255  , -1.84388812, -0.37092441,  0.27572306,
    2.57470918,  3.860485  ,  4.62580789,  5.34147103,  6.68231985,
    7.38242258,  8.28346559,  9.46008873, 10.69300274, 12.46051285,
   13.35049975, 13.28279961, 14.31604781, 16.8226239 , 16.81708308,
   18.64342284, 19.37375515, 19.6714002 , 20.13700708, 22.72327533])

y_uncertainties = array([ 0.63543112,  1.07608924,  0.83603265, -0.03442888, -0.07049299,
    1.30864191,  1.36015322,  1.42125414,  1.04099854,  1.20556608,
    0.43749964,  1.635056  ,  1.00627014,  0.40512511,  1.19638787,
    1.26230966,  0.68253139,  0.98055035,  1.01512232,  1.83910276,
    0.96763007,  0.57373151,  1.69358475,  0.62068133,  0.70030971,
    0.34648312,  1.85234844,  1.18687269,  1.23841579,  1.19741206])
```

With this data I obtain that `scale_factor = 1.6534129347542432`, `my_scale_factor = 1.653412934754234` and that the "nominal" scale factor reported in the documentation, i.e.

```
nominal_scale_factor = np.sum((y_obs - popt[0] * x_data  - popt[1])**2 /\  
                               y_uncertainties**2) / np.sqrt(len(y_obs) - len(y_obs) + 2)
```

has value `nominal_scale_factor = 32.73590595145554`

PS. my numpy version is
`1.18.5 3.7.7 (default, May  6 2020, 11:45:54) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Comment: If I run this (with `np.__version__ == '1.18.1'`), `my_scale_factor` and `scale_factor` always have the same value, although the value varies a lot depending on the random seed, so it's consistent with dividing by `N-nDOF`.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys could you elaborate more clearly? The formula for the scaling factor is deterministic, so it is either right or wrong ...

Comment: Could you please provide the numbers generated by your code and explain why they are not what you expect them to be?

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys I add the data in the main post

Comment: Your expression for `nominal_scale_factor` generates errors. `len(y_obs)` looks suspicious. So does the square root.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys sorry there was a wrong sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the `numpy.polyfit` documentation:

> By default, the covariance are scaled by chi2/sqrt(N-dof), i.e., the weights are presumed to be unreliable except in a relative sense and everything is scaled such that the reduced chi2 is unity.

This looks like a documentation bug. The correct scaling factor for the covariance is `chi_square/(N-M)` where `M` is the number of fit parameters and `N-M` is the number of degrees of freedom. It looks like `np.polyfit` is implemented correctly, because `my_scale_factor` and `scale_factor` are consistent.

Regarding the question on why not "the square of the inverse of the y-data errors": a polynomial fit or more generally, a least-squares fit involves solving the `p` vector in

```
A @ p = y
```

where `A` is an `(N, M)` matrix for `N` data points in `y` and `M` elements in `p` and each column in `A` is the polynomial term evaluated at the corresponding `x` values.

The solution minimizes

```
    (SUM_j A[i, j] p[j] - y[i])^2
SUM -----------------------------
 i           sigma_y[i]^2
```

Computationally, the cheapest way to calculate this is by multiplying each row in `A` and each `y` value by the corresponding `1/sigma_y` and then taking a standard least-square solution of the `A@p=y` equation. By having the user supply the inverse errors, it saves the fit routine from handling division by zero issues and slow square-root operations.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part, I opened a Github issue

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16842

The conclusion on that thread is that the documentation is wrong, but the function behaves correctly.

The documentation should be updated to

> By default, the covariance is scaled by **chi2/dof**, i.e., the weights are presumed to be unreliable except in a relative sense and everything is scaled such that the reduced chi2 is unity.